# Want to run a Speaker/Amplifier combo from a rechargeable battery

Tags: power-supply, batteries, power-electronics

I want to run [**KRK RP5 G2 Studio Monitors**](http://www.krksys.com/manuals/rokit/rpg2_manual.pdf)  off battery for at least 1 hour.
These are a combination of speakers plus amplifier in the one unit with AC power input.

I do not want to use car battery inverter solution as they are heavy and risky.
The back panel states 100W
and the [manual](http://www.krksys.com/manuals/rokit/rpg2_manual.pdf) says
Power Output = 45W 
High Frequency =  15W 
Low frequency = 30W

Please suggest me some off the self solution or the steps to build one.

Answer (score 2):

Since the KRK RP5 G2 amplifier/speaker unit doesn't have a DC power input, your best bet really is an external inverter powered by a large battery.

Anything else would require you to make changes to the internal circuitry of the power supply of the RP5.  There might be a circuit diagram for the RP5 available somewhere, but even with one I think you would need a good bit of support to make the needed changes and additions.

Mechanically, you would need to install a power jack for the DC input.  Electronically, you would need some kind of switching power supply to convert the supplied DC to the voltages needed for the amplifier.  It probably needs a positive and negative supply voltage for the power stage, and may need lower voltages for other functions.  If you try to supply those voltages, then you would likely need to isolate the original power supply when using your DC power in.

As you see, the changes aren't trivial.

Given that the RP5 requires 100W of input power, you would still need a fairly large battery even if you were to modify the unit to accept DC in.

An inverter will have losses, so you will need a larger battery for the same run time compared to a more efficient DC input.  I think you will still be better served with an external inverter.

100W for 1 hour is 100watt hours of energy.  A car battery with a capacity of 120Ampere Hours (~1400Watt Hours) would be enough for 14 hours (assuming no losses) so it should run several hours when powering the amp through an inverter.

A 20 Amp Hour motorcycle battery ought to be capable of powering the amplifier through an inverter for close to an hour.

---

Added in response to comment:

If you are concerned about using a car battery, you could use a sealed lead acid battery.

These are similar to car batteries (at least chemistry wise) but are sealed so they don't leak and can be more easily transported.

I find plenty of them with capacities high enough to provide an hour of usage (even allowing for losses through the inverter) at reasonable prices - around US$ 40 for a 200WattHour  battery that ought to easily provide power for an hour.

Comment: Hi @JRE, Isn't lead acid batteries dangerous and heavy? They cannot be tilted or need to have fixed upward orientation.

Comment: @Akash: Flooded lead-acid batteries do contain liquid, so must be kept upright.  There are also Gel Cell and AGM lead-acid batteries which are sealed (sometimes called "SLA" for "Sealed lead-acid) that don't have any liquid electrolyte - these can be used in any position.

Answer (score 1):

As JRE says, without modifying the speakers there is no way to run them from other than an AC supply at "mains" voltages (either 110 VAC or 230 VAC).

Modern fully sealed lead acid batteries are safe to transport without risk of electrolyte spillage. They can be carried in any orientation and can usually be used in any orientation.

If preferred their are alternatives such as LiFePO4 batteries which are significantly lighter and have longer lifetimes and usually lower whole of life costs that lead acid (but higher purchase price.)

---

Assume a "reference power level" to start of 10 Watts input.
In one hour that requires 10 Watt hours of energy.
A 12V battery will use about 1 Ah of capacity to provide 10 Watts for 1 hour.

A typical alarm "brick" battery of 7Ah currentxtime capacity has an all used capacity of 12V x 7Ah = 84 Watt hours of capacity. Using this to only 50% of total capacity to extend lifetime gives =~ 40 Watt hours and 25% capacity gives 20 Wh.

The amount of energy needed depends on use - very loud completely continuous output MAY require 50W+ of output - but probably not.  After allowing for inverter losses a 7Ah battery is liable to be on the low side. Something like 12V at 20 to 40 Ah would be better. A 12V 40 Ah lead acid battery is the size of a large car battery. But a LiFPO4 battery of the same capacity is half the size and perhaps half the weight - and maybe double or more x the cost.

A 20 Ah or even 40 Ah LiFePO4 battery plus 12V to 110 VAC or 230 VAC inverter could be built into a tidy safe housing that was smaller than the speaker and possibly about the same weight or less. A lead acid battery should not be discharged to less than 50% of its full capacity and less discharge again is better. Some say that LiFePO4 can be safely discharged 100% BUT limiting discharge to 70% or less is wise. Advice on chargers and charging schemes can be obtained from the battery sellers.

Comment: Thanks...If you are saying LeFePO4 20Ah with inverter will work....Excellent..

Comment: @Akash Subject to some of the constraints I mentioned. Let's try a calculation: 12 V x 20 AH x 70% discharge x say 80% conversion efficiency = 124 Watt hour. That sounds like it would meet your spec well with some allowance for even lower discharge depth and lower inverter efficiency. | Chemistry is LiFePO4 or LiFeYPO4 - Lithium Ferro Phosphate - or with Yttrium in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Heavy, yes.  (car batteries *are* lead, after all)  But not necessarily dangerous in terms of spilling chemicals.  Unsealed wet cells are, and this may be what you're thinking of, but a sealed gel should be fine.  It doesn't eat your fender when you take a sharp turn.

However, with any decent-sized battery, you do have to be aware of how much energy it can store and how fast it can release that energy.  For the application you're thinking of, that's "a lot" and "pretty quick".  Make sure that nothing conductive ever touches the terminals unless you explicitly want it to.

If you're *very* lucky, you *might* find that the AC input can also take DC to the tune of what the AC peak would have been.  This would be because the power supply rectifies it immediately to power a switching stage that requires a DC input.  But if you're unlucky, you can blow up an expensive transformer or cause similar damage by doing that, which is probably not covered by the warranty.  Also, if you're unlucky, you'll get yourself across the terminals of a 170VDC source, and...well...let's just say that you won't make that or any other mistake again.

Much better to use a 12V battery and inverter.